# Extracting distinct list of duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql

If I have a table like the one below:

| ID | BOOKING_NUM |
| --- | --- |
| John | 123 |
| Bill | 124 |
| Abby | 234 |
| Abby | 365 |
| Luis | 983 |
| Luis | 984 |

How can I extract a list of distinct IDs that have more than one booking using SQL?

I have tried the following code but can't seem to get the correct result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM bookings HAVING COUNT(ID) >1
```

Comment: you have to group by id :`SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM bookings GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID) >1`

Comment: AFAIK you should always use `GROUP BY` when using `HAVING`   W3Shools says: "The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword cannot be used with aggregate functions." [*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) But it is missing the reason that HAVING is applied on the results of an aggregate expression

Comment: @eshirvana Why do you want to use both DISTINCT and GROUP BY? Using both in one query is mostly redundant and I don't see why to use DISTINCT here.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Copied their query didn’t notice the distinct

Answer (score 1):

Your query is almost there but you need to aggregate using *group by*

This groups the rows based on unique values in the column(s) you group by, then *having* filters by looking at the number of rows in each group.

```
select id 
from t
group by id
having Count(*) > 1;
```